# Did Star Trek TNG's Mr. Data ever do a facepalm?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Did Data ever do a facepalm?

I'm open to anything in the series, the bloopers, the movies, or even just Brent Spiner in costume in other contexts such as conventions.

I've been researching this and I've found every major TNG Starfleet officer facepalming, except for Data.

For example:

[image]

Comment: http://i726.photobucket.com/albums/ww264/spockynkirky/BrentSpinerFacepalm.png

Comment: @Valorum Nice! You find some obscure stuff. So we have Brent Spiner facepalming, but he wasn't good enough to put on the makeup and costume for us.

Comment: Although Picard does facepalm, I'm pretty sure that that shot is edited to make him appear with a facepalm.

Comment: @Xantec The Picard part of it is real, but the Riker facepalm is photoshopped in from a totally different episode. I have a version of it with Worf too.

Comment: Picard in this shot looks entirely unreal - it would make sense for Riker to be facepalming in this episode (where he is on trial for murder)

Comment: “I've been researching this and I've found every major TNG Starfleet officer facepalming except Data” — grant money well spent +1.

Comment: I think you should re-open your Vulcan question. It's answerable. Be brave :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning of this video, at 0:09, you can see him putting his hand to his face, but he goes offscreen and I can't tell if he actually touches.

Comment: Enough time has gone by that I think we can edit this to say "No he doesn't, but this is the closest thing" and then it can be the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I remember an old interview with Brent Spiner (Maybe Starlog magazine). He said in Data makeup he had to learn not to touch his face. So maybe he never did a facepalm because it would mess up all the hard work of the makeup crew.

Comment: A quote would turn this from good to excellent

Comment: I can't see anything about the makeup in the [Starlog interview with Brent Spiner](https://archive.org/stream/starlog_magazine-221/221#page/n25/mode/2up/search/brent+spiner).

Comment: This is a good answer and I would mark it as accepted if it had a solid reference.